# Pandas | Alternative for lambda function => .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, pandas

I have a method that calculates a weighted average from two columns of a pandas dataframe. Since these columns are not of the float datatype, they have to be converted into the appropriate format first. After the calculation they are converted back to the original format.

```
def calculate_weighted_average(self, dataframe, column_for_average, column_for_weight):
    a = dataframe[column_for_average]
    w = dataframe[column_for_weight]
    # convert german decimal to float
    a = a.apply( lambda x : self.convert_german_decimal_to_float(x) )
    # calulate average
    weighted_average = (a * w).sum() / w.sum()
    # convert float to german decimal 
    weighted_average = self.convert_float_to_german_decimal(weighted_average)
    return weighted_average
```

For the conversion I use Lambda function, which generates a warning message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

How can I define this method with .loc?

Comment: It's not the usage of `lambda` per-se that causes the warning, but the fact that `a` is a subset of `dataframe`

Comment: `a = dataframe[column_for_average].copy()` should solve the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Ignore the Warning, But if you don't want warning
try this

```
def calculate_weighted_average(self, dataframe, column_for_average, column_for_weight):
    a = dataframe[column_for_average]
    w = dataframe[column_for_weight]
    # convert german decimal to float
    a1 = a.apply( lambda x : self.convert_german_decimal_to_float(x))
    # calulate average
    weighted_average = (a1 * w).sum() / w.sum()
    # convert float to german decimal 
    weighted_average = self.convert_float_to_german_decimal(weighted_average)
    return weighted_average
```